# Twitter Bootstrap Navigation without the framework

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to achieve the twitter bootstrap navigation without using the twitter bootstrap framework. Here is my code pen http://www.codepen.io/anon/pen/Kedzl. Below is the image I want to achieve once the width of the `.wrap` reaches a certain specified width.

[image]

I have been searching for the JavaScript code to replicate this effect, but I haven't found it. The example can be found on and it's supporting documentation on http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/tuts/312_bs/My-Bootstrap-Site-NAVBAR/navbar-examples.html

Comment: Could you point me in the direction of these styles? I just can't seem to find them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

you could go here and just grab the nav